# Operational Error at / No such table after push to heroku

Tags: html, django, heroku, operationalerror

Currently works on local environment, but after pushing to heroku and visiting my live page I get an OperationalError at /.  It looks like I can not run any for loops at all.  I just want to add I am doing the djangogirl tutorial and am a newbie.

> OperationalError at / no such table: blog_post
>
> Error during template rendering
>
> In template /app/blog/templates/blog/post_list.html, error at line 5 ( {% for post in posts %})

here is post_list.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published.date }}
            </div>
            <h1><a href="{% url 'blog.views.post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
            <p> {{ post.text|linebreaks }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Here is my .gitignore:

```
myvenv
__pycache__
staticfiles
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
```

Additional information:
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://girlsblog.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 1.7.7
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:
no such table: blog_post
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 485
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:
['/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-15.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 18 May 2015 19:20:07 -0500

Answer (score 1):

Did you run your initial migrates on heroku?

```
$ heroku run bash
$ ./manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I did not, and I tried, but I'm not sure what is supposed to happen with what you said.  If I do heroku run bash (while on my virtual env) it "runs" but then leaves me w/ ~ $  (no path).  And I am confused what to do. 

I have been using git and have not had to migrate.

Comment: You have at some point ran syncdb or migrate (depends on your version of django) on your local machine to create your database schema. On Heroku you need to also run that command to create your database schema. After you open your bash console on heroku ( $ heroku run bash ) if you run ./manage.py migrate the error will go away. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/

Comment: @djangogirl I see now you're running django 1.7, in that ~ $ (no path) run ./manage.py migrate and your error will go away because your database schema will be created

Comment: Yes I had one migration in the beginning, but none thereafter.  After I do "./manage.py migrate" in bash i get "bash: ./manage.py: Permission denied"

Comment: Also if I just go to my virtual env, and do
    python manage.py migrate
it says no migrations to apply.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error in my Heroku app.

Adding this in *blog/settings.py* will fix it.

This will update database configuration from $DATABASE_URL.

```
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Source :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment